# Async.waterfall: Callback already was called on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I am fully aware that there are questions here which are trying to address the issue I am raising here.

I have gone through all of them try to implement the answers which are given on these threads but have not succeeded. The error I am getting when I am trying to implement async.waterfall() is Callback was already called.

I hope to get some pointers from where I could make it work. Thank you.

```
getTodayDetail: function(cId,endTime,user,callback){
        console.log('Lets begin here');
        console.log('clinic id :'+cId);
        console.log('endtime for appoinment '+endTime);
        var ett = new Date();
        ett.setSeconds(0);
        ett.setHours(0);
        ett.setMinutes(0);
        var cid = cId;
        console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(cid));
        //var clinicId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(clinicId);
        //ett.setHours(00,00,1).toISOString();
        console.log("Value of et variable after setHours function "+ett);
       // var et = moment(endTime).utcOffset("+00:00").format('ddd MMM DD YYYY');
        async.waterfall([
            function f1 (callback){
                console.log('f1 from getTodayDetails '+cid);
                console.log("endTime "+endTime);
                appointment.find({ 
                    clinicId: cid, 
                    endTime: { $gte: ett, $lte: endTime }}, function(err, appointmentdetails){
                    if(err)
                    {
                        callback(err,null);
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }else
                    {
                        callback(null, appointmentdetails);
                        console.log("Success "+appointmentdetails);
                    }
                })
            },
            function f2(appointmentdetails, callback) {
                console.log("from f2 content of appointmentdetails :"+appointmentdetails.data);
                for (var i = 0; i<appointmentdetails.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log("Success f2");
                    Temppay.find(({appointmentId: appointmentdetails[i]._id}),function(err, result2){
                        if(err)
                        {
                            callback(err, null);
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }else{
                            callback(null, result2, appointmentdetails);
                            console.log("from f2 content of result2 "+result2.data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            function f3(result2, appointmentdetails, callback){
                for(var i = 0; i<result2.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log("f3 Success");
                    patient.find(({"_id": result2[i].patientId}), function(err, result3){
                        if(err)
                        {
                            callback(err, null);
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            callback(null, result3,result2,appointmentdetails);
                        }
                    })
                }

            }
        ], function(err, result3, result2,appointmentdetails){
            if(err)
            {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }else
            {
                var appoinmentoftoday = appointmentdetails;
                var paymentdetails = result2;
                var patientdetails = result3;
                console.log("Today's appointments"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(appoinmentoftoday)));
                console.log("Today's appointment payment details"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result2)));
                console.log("Today's appointments patient details "+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result3)));

            }
        })
},
```

This is from terminal what I am getting as error

```
from f2 content of result2 undefined

    0|app      | Error: Callback was already called.
    0|app      |     at /home/test_user/Server/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:955:32
    0|app      |     at /home/test_user/Server/app/service/appointmentService.js:1661:29
    0|app      |     at model.Query.<anonymous> (/home/test_user/Server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3764:16)
    0|app      |     at /home/test_user/Server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:277:21
    0|app      |     at /home/test_user/Server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    0|app      |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    0|app      |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the callback method multiple times by running it inside a loop.

> The callback is supposed to be called only once.

Instead, you can push the results of the loop to an array and call the callback method with the array.

Update:-

```
function f2(appointmentdetails, callback) {
    Promise.all(appointmentdetails.map((appointment) => {
        return Temppay.find({appointmentId: appointment._id});
    })).then((results) => {
        callback(null, results, appointmentdetails);
    });
}
```

Why don't you replace your method like the above?

Comment: do you mean something like this appointmentdetails.foreach(Res) {appointmentdetails.data.push(res)}  ?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: I didn't understand how this will help ?